# What is the difference between "primary quantum yield" and quantum yield?

Tags: physical-chemistry, photochemistry

The definition of the **primary quantum yield** given in Atkins textbook Physical chemistry as "The primary quantum yield, φ, is defined as the number of photophysical or photochemical events that lead to primary products divided by the number of photons absorbed by the molecule in the same interval."

And from Wiki: The general definition of the **quantum yield** (Φ) of a radiation-induced process - it is the number of times a specific event occurs per photon absorbed by the system.

And both sources use the same equation for Φ:
$$\displaystyle Φ=\frac{Number~of~events}{Number~of~photons~absorbed}$$

Is there any special use for term "Primary quantum yield" (I haven't found the explanation in literature)?

Comment: It does not seem particularly problematic. I guess the book wording point more precisely to a specific event/reaction right after absorption. Say, there is a QY for forming a reactive species and a generally small QY that lead to the final product (by a step in which photons are even not involved), etc. Or the QY of luminescence in not the same as that of absorption itself, which is unity.

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful! And I also looked through Braslavsky, S. E. (2007-01-01). "Glossary of terms used in photochemistry, 3rd edition (IUPAC Recommendations 2006)". It gives definition only for quantum yield but distinguishes the integrated, differential  QY's and also photochemical reaction QY. Thus, I don't see the need to use term the primary QY.

Comment: Primary quantum yield would seem to be unnecessary. Most,  if not all,  of the literature will use the Wike definition.